# can browser control on c# can keep the url

Tags: c#, url, browser

I want one bottom when click it keep the url of the browser to database The process that bring text to database i can do how can i create a bottom to send the url that browser are visiting

Comment: The question is not clear, please explain more clearly

Comment: Please reframe your question, as it is not clear. Although what i could understood was that you want to save the current brwoser URL to database on click of a button using C# code ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?..Do you want the current URL??

Answer (score 0):

You can get your current url from c# by

```
Request.Url //returns as string
```

for more information see [here](http://www.xcess.info/request_url_parameters_details_asp_net_aen.aspx).